# How to access Images form Drawable using Dynamic String Path

Tags: android, android-layout, drawable, android-image

I have this type of image path

```
       String img_path = "R.drawable."+lower+"_25";
```

lower contain dynamic name of images...

this images are already in drawable how to show images in my

ImageView in android

Comment: is lower a file inside the drawable.?or u want the string be in (suppose)listview .and view it in image view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make constructor in your adapter

```
public class MyAdapter extends XXXXXXX{
Context con;
public MyAdapter(Context con) {
        this.con = con;

    }

 .
 .
 .
int id = con.getResources().getIdentifier(lower+"_25", "drawable", "<your package name>");
imageView.setBackgroundResource(image_id);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the id of the image in the drawable using it's name, using:

```
int image_id = getResources().getIdentifier(lower+"_25", "drawable", getPackageName());
imageView.setBackgroundResource(image_id);
```

Comment: getResources() is not support because it is in adapter not in Activity

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
getResources().getIdentifier(lower+"_25", "drawable", getPackageName())
```

Comment: getResources()  is not support because it is in adapter not in Activity

Comment: @AmitPrajapati FYI, To access getResources() method, you have to have [context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html). Now as you are in adapter, you should pass context of current activity, and then inside you can access by using: `context.getResources()`